# Apache flink Kafka Avro serialized streaming from topic with multiple event types(TopicRecordNameStrategy for the subject in the schema registry))

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have written a consumer to read the topic and build a Datastream of GenericRecord, but the topic contains messages with different schemas as we are using TopicRecordNameStrategy for the subject in the schema registry.

Below is my consumer code :

```
ParameterTool parameters = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);
            LOGGER.info("Input Parameters Map: " + parameters.toMap());

           
            StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

            if (parameters.get(CHECK_POINTS_DIR) != null && !parameters.get(CHECK_POINTS_DIR).isBlank()) {
                env.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointStorage(new FileSystemCheckpointStorage(parameters.get(
                        CHECK_POINTS_DIR)));
            }

            env.enableCheckpointing(Integer.parseInt(parameters.get(CHECKPOINT_INTERVAL_IN_SECS)) * 1000L);
            env.getCheckpointConfig().setMinPauseBetweenCheckpoints(Integer.parseInt(parameters.get(
                    PAUSE_BETWEEN_CHECKPOINTS_IN_SECS)) * 1000L);
            env.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointingMode(EXACTLY_ONCE);
            env.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointTimeout(Integer.parseInt(parameters.get(
                    CHECKPOINT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECS)) * 1000L);
            env.getCheckpointConfig().setMaxConcurrentCheckpoints(1);
            env.getCheckpointConfig().setExternalizedCheckpointCleanup(RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION);

           
            Properties kafkaProperties = new Properties();
            kafkaProperties.setProperty("partition.discovery.interval.ms",String.valueOf(parameters.getInt(KAFKA_PARTITION_DISCOVERY_INTERVAL_IN_SECS) * 1000));
            kafkaProperties.setProperty("value.subject.name.strategy", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy");



            KafkaSource<GenericRecord> kafkaSource =
                    KafkaSource.<GenericRecord>builder()
                            .setProperties(kafkaProperties)
                            .setBootstrapServers(parameters.get(BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS))
                            .setTopics("sucheth-test-topic-recrd-strategy")
                            .setGroupId(GROUP_ID)
                            .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
                            .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new AvroDataDeserializationSchema(
                                    "sucheth-test-topic-recrd-strategy",
                                    parameters.get(SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL)))
                            .build();

            DataStream<GenericRecord> dataStream =
                    env.fromSource(
                                    kafkaSource,
                                    WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(),
                                    "Kafka Source")
                            //should be a unique id
                            .uid("kafka-source");

            dataStream.print();
```

My Custom Avro GenericRecord Deserialization :

```
public class AvroDataDeserializationSchema extends AbstractDeserializationSchema<GenericRecord> {
    private final Class<GenericRecord> avrotype = (Class<GenericRecord>) org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord.class;

    private Schema schema;
    private final String registryUrl;

    private final String topic;

    private transient KafkaAvroDeserializer kafkaAvroDeserializerClient;

    public AvroDataDeserializationSchema(String topic, String registryUrl) {
        //Schema schema) {
        this.registryUrl = registryUrl;
        this.topic = topic;
    }

    /**
     * Initialization method for the schema. It is called before the actual working methods
     * {@link #deserialize} and thus suitable for one time setup work.
     *
     * <p>The provided {@link InitializationContext} can be used to access additional features such
     * as e.g. registering user metrics.
     *
     * @param context Contextual information that can be used during initialization.
     */
    @Override
    public void open(InitializationContext context) throws Exception {
        super.open(context);
    }

    /**
     * De-serializes the byte message.
     *
     * @param message The message, as a byte array.
     * @return The de-serialized message as an object.
     */
    @Override
    public GenericRecord deserialize(byte[] message) throws IOException {
        try {
            checkInitialized();
        } catch (RestClientException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        var record = (GenericRecord) kafkaAvroDeserializerClient.deserialize(topic, message);
        return record;
    }

    private void checkInitialized() throws RestClientException, IOException {
        if (kafkaAvroDeserializerClient == null) {
            Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
            props.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, registryUrl);
            props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, false);
            SchemaRegistryClient client = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(
                    registryUrl,
                    AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.MAX_SCHEMAS_PER_SUBJECT_DEFAULT);
            kafkaAvroDeserializerClient = new KafkaAvroDeserializer(client, props);


        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEndOfStream(GenericRecord nextElement) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public TypeInformation<GenericRecord> getProducedType() {

        return TypeExtractor.getForClass(avrotype);
    }
```

when i submit this application to flink cluster it is falling back to kryo deserialization and fails with the below error (However works when i run it from INTELLIJ IDE for some unknown reason)

```
rint to Std. Out (1/1) (0b773e3dadbe0951d75d5172e400a206) switched from RUNNING to FAILED on localhost:57062-e6cc01 @ localhost (dataPort=57064).
java.io.IOException: Failed to deserialize consumer record due to
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.reader.KafkaRecordEmitter.emitRecord(KafkaRecordEmitter.java:56) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.reader.KafkaRecordEmitter.emitRecord(KafkaRecordEmitter.java:33) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.SourceReaderBase.pollNext(SourceReaderBase.java:143) ~[flink-connector-files-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.SourceOperator.emitNext(SourceOperator.java:385) ~[flink-dist-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTaskSourceInput.emitNext(StreamTaskSourceInput.java:68) ~[flink-dist-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamOneInputProcessor.processInput(StreamOneInputProcessor.java:65) ~[flink-dist-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.processInput(StreamTask.java:519) ~[flink-dist-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:203) ~[flink-dist-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:804) ~[flink-dist-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:753) ~[flink-dist-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:948) ~[flink-dist-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:927) ~[flink-dist-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:741) ~[flink-dist-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:563) ~[flink-dist-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[?:?]
Caused by: org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ExceptionInChainedOperatorException: Could not forward element to next operator
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:99) ~[flink-dist-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:57) ~[flink-dist-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:29) ~[flink-dist-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceOperatorStreamTask$AsyncDataOutputToOutput.emitRecord(SourceOperatorStreamTask.java:313) ~[flink-dist-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.source.SourceOutputWithWatermarks.collect(SourceOutputWithWatermarks.java:110) ~[flink-dist-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.reader.KafkaRecordEmitter$SourceOutputWrapper.collect(KafkaRecordEmitter.java:67) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.DeserializationSchema.deserialize(DeserializationSchema.java:84) ~[flink-dist-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.reader.deserializer.KafkaValueOnlyDeserializationSchemaWrapper.deserialize(KafkaValueOnlyDeserializationSchemaWrapper.java:51) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.reader.KafkaRecordEmitter.emitRecord(KafkaRecordEmitter.java:53) ~[?:?]
    ... 14 more
Caused by: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
Serialization trace:
reserved (org.apache.avro.Schema$Field)
fieldMap (org.apache.avro.Schema$RecordSchema)
schema (org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125) ~[flink-dist-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
```

I checked this doc on GenericRecord TypeInformation as mentioned [here](https://flink.apache.org/news/2020/04/15/flink-serialization-tuning-vol-1.html#avro), but that is not what I want. My topic is not bound to one particular schema but has messages with multiple schemas as we are using TopicRecordNameStrategy for the subject with confluent schema registry

Please help me in resolving this.

Comment: Seems like you should be using a `ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema`.

Comment: Hi for that I need to provide a reader schema.. there are below issues, 1. As a consumer I shouldn’t be storing a schema 2. My topic has different schema’s

Comment: Actually, I have the same issue with ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchemaforGeneric(schema, schemaRegistryUrl). I am able to read the message, get a GenericRecord (and get data with custom code linked to bytes) but when I want to move the GenericRecord to a windowed stream (I have the GenericRecord field in the bean I manage in the main stream). It cannot be deserialize. Any idea?

Comment: sorry i didn't understand. may be piece of code would help me to trouble shoot.

Comment: @SuchethShivakumar, did you solved your `ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema` issue? If yes, please share.